# What do we mean when we say an irrational number can't be expressed as a fraction?

Tags: irrational-numbers

An irrational number is one such that it cannot be expressed by a fraction, but consider the definition of the Golden Ratio.

Two line segments, call one a and the other b, are said to be of the Golden Ratio if:
$${{a + b} \over a} = {a \over b} = \varphi $$

How can,

$${a \over b} = \varphi $$

be the case if an irrational number cannot be expressed as a fraction?

Comment: Well, since $\phi$ is irrational, it means that $a$ and $b$ can't both be integers. A fraction is a ratio of $2$ integers.

Comment: $\phi=[1;1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,\ldots]$

Comment: Indeed, you can write $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ but this does not make it rational as the fraction has an irrational numerator in this case.

Comment: @jimbo While correct, what does this help the questioner? ^^

Comment: @jimbo While correct,  I doubt that that notation is familiar to the original questioner :)

Comment: For anyone who likes continued fractions, in some sense $\phi$ is the _most_ irrational number, because its continued fraction expansion uses the smallest values possible. (A rational number has a finite number of integers in its continued fraction  expansion, effectively followed by an $\infty$---so not small.) This is why it shows up in seed heads. If seeds are released at rational angles relative to a whole revolution they will end up clustered too close. It's this sense of being far away from rational that causes $\phi$ to be a good proportion of a revolution for seeds to be released.

Comment: @jimbo While correct, previous to this I wasn't familiar with the notation you're using.

Comment: I just can't believe I went all these years without knowing an irrational number cannot be expressed as a fraction of integers. (No jokes please)  The belief that all numbers can be represented by such a fraction must have been important to the ancient mathematicians.  The discovery of irrational numbers (Hippasus?) must have really freaked them out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your definition of irrational is incomplete.  A number is irrational if it cannot be expressed in terms of $\frac a b$ where both $a$ and $b$ are INTEGERS ($b\ne 0$).   In this case, the $a$ and $b$ are not simultaneously integers, so it is irrational.

Edit for further clarity:

If the restriction of "integers" was removed, then every number would be "rational",  because $a=\frac a 1$

Comment: That is helpful because I thought a and or b can be any real number.  I greatly appreciate the help from all of you and it makes much more sense now!

Comment: My pleasure!  Good learning.

Comment: Note that if they could be any real number then $a = \frac{a}{1}$ implies everything is rational.

Answer (score 5):

An irrational number is one that cannot be expressed by a fraction of *integers*.